# Irradiance Volumes vs. Tiled Deferred Shading

Tags: directx-11, compute-shader, deferred-rendering

I have a renderer in DirectX 11 that uses deferred shading and tiled light culling on the compute shader. I can run 1024-2048 point lights with a steady framerate of 30-35 FPS. I however do not have global illumination.Are irradiance volumes (used in Crysis3) a better solution? Can you have 2000 irradiance volumes on scene and have 30 FPS? Or should I stick to my current method and forget about global illumination?